# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined when call method of injected provider in NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Follow tutorial at [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers), I'm just implement simple NestJS app with a module have injected provider below:

```
# app.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config'

import { AuthModule } from '@/modules/auth/auth.module'

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    AuthModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
# auth.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'

import { AuthController } from '@/modules/auth/auth.controller'
import { AuthService } from '@/modules/auth/auth.service'

@Module({
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

```
# auth.controller.ts

import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AuthService } from '@/modules/auth/auth.service'

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor (private readonly service: AuthService) {}

  @Get('me')
  public getSelfInfo (): string {
    return this.service.getSelfInfo()
  }
}
```

```
# auth.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  getSelfInfo (): string {
    return 'ok'
  }
}
```

But when call to endpoint, this error thrown:

[Nest] 17196  - 09/23/2022, 2:34:18 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSelfInfo')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSelfInfo')
at AuthController.getSelfInfo (/dist/modules/auth/auth.controller.js:16:29)

Please tell me which problem at here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue when add code block below to `app.controller.ts`:

```
@Inject(AuthService)
private readonly service: AuthService

constructor (service: AuthService) {
  this.service = service
}
```

Comment: Interesting, this shouldn't be necessary. If `undefined` is being injected, is there any circular references between the service and controller, possibly through a barrel file?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when I added

```
"type": "module"
```

to my `package.json` because i need to use an ES module.

I had to update all imports and add the extension to the path.

```
import { ProductsService } from './products.service';
```

becomes

```
import { ProductsService } from './products.service.js';
```

After that i had the same Problem like @Dan Tran.  His Solution works, but i have to refactor my whole project.

Is this the only solution or is anything missing there? Because Jay McDoniel say it shouldn't be neccessary.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34012515)